# org babel exports code blocks even if I tell it to export results instead

Tags: org-export, org-babel, pdf

How can I make `org-babel` only export results, not code? The only way I've found to suppress code from appearing in the output is to comment out all the code blocks manually. I tried adding `:exports results` but it still includes the code.

I'm using Emacs 25.2 with org-mode 9.0.6.

Comment: You mean that `:exports results` has no effects? `#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports results` works fine for me and the export only includes results and no code. Can you show us your src block?

Comment: Good point. I used R in my source blocks. But, I was worried that I was misunderstanding what `:exports results` was trying to do.

Comment: Have a look at the [org docs about exporting](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-code-blocks.html). They explain all options and what they do.